# Angular ngstorage and satellizer localstorage prefix conflict

Tags: angularjs, local-storage, prefix, satellizer, ng-storage

I use [ngstorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage), [satellizer](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer) angular modules for my app. But I have problem with storage prefix configuration.

For **ngstorage**:

- It saves data as: `NGSTORAGE_PREFIXkey = value`
- Default prefix is: 'ngStorage-'

For **satellizer**:

- It saves data as: `SATELLIZER_PREFIX_key = value`
- default prefix is: 'satellizer' with additional underscore ( _ ) before key

As we know, after `$auth.login()` token is saved to localStorage as `satellizer_token = SOME_TOKEN`

I want to use ngstorage for all operations with localStorage, in particular I need to access `satellizer_token` which was saved to localStorage before. For that purpose I need to set the same prefix for both modules like in code below

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('App', [
    'satellizer',
    'ngStorage'
])

.config(function($authProvider, $localStorageProvider) {

    // Local Storage config
    $localStorageProvider.setKeyPrefix('myprefix_');

    // Auth Provider config
    $authProvider.tokenPrefix = 'myprefix_';
});
```

**controller.js**

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $localStorage) {

    // Storage
    $scope.$storage = $localStorage;

    // Set some data
    $scope.$storage.mykey = myvalue;

    // other code...
});
```

**view.js**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    {{$storage.mykey}}
    {{$storage._token}}
<div>
```

After `$auth.login()` view is compiled well, shows `$storage.mykey` value (i.e. myvalue), but nothing for `$storage._token`. But after reload a page, view isn't compiled at all, and shows

```
{{$storage.mykey}}
{{$storage._token}}
```

It seems there is some conflict.

What's your solutions for this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, found solution to access token via $auth.getToken() function.